# i want to know what b[...] means in the python

Tags: python, numpy

I saw the below function in one place:

> ```
> import numpy as np
> def cube(data_set):
>     new_data_set=np.nditer([data_set, None])
>     for a,b in new_data_set:
>         b[...]=a*a*a
>     return new_data_set.operands[1]
> Data_set=np.arange(3)
> print(cube(Data_set))
> ```

What I am not able to understand is the use the part `b[...]`.
What are the 3 dosts exactly doing here or in general?

Comment: It is equivalent to `b.__getitem__(Ellipsis)` and what it exactly does depends on the implementation of `b`. See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis

Comment: It's like `b[:]=...``but more general.  And required by this use of `nditer`.  Don't spend too much time on this bit of code.  Beginners shouldn't be using `nditer`.